# Krename: how to restart numbering for every folder?

Tags: kde, rename

I have 4 folders with 3 folders each. after the rename operation, I will have

```
folder1
  - file1.txt
  - file2.txt
  - file3.txt
folder2
  - file1.txt
  - file2.txt
  - file3.txt
and so on.
```

When I try to use [$dirname]####, I get

```
folder1
  - file1.txt
  - file2.txt
  - file3.txt
folder2
  - file4.txt
  - file5.txt
  - file6.txt
and so on.
```

any idea how it's done? Thanks

Comment: *after the rename operation* - what was exactly renamed in your case?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest edited original post. Thanks

Comment: 1) `[$dirname]####` doesn't look as renaming command; 2) *with 3 folders each* - maybe, 3 FILES each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In KRename 4.0.9:

1. Add the files
2. Go to tab *Filename* -> *Advanced Filename*
3. Edit the template
4. Click *Numbering...*
5. Select *Reset counter for every directory*

[image]